# Tomcat but not Jetty: NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.JoinColumn.foreignKey()Ljavax/persistence/ForeignKey

Tags: spring, hibernate, tomcat, jetty, wicket

I have recently upgraded my Wicket 6 application from Spring 3 to Spring 4.

When I run the application locally on Jetty 7, it runs fine.

When I deploy it to Tomcat 7, I get the following error:

> [2014-05-07 10:20:47,121] ERROR [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader] Context initialization failed 
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.JoinColumn.foreignKey()Ljavax/persistence/ForeignKey;

Is this a Tomcat issue or should I just go ahead and try to solve the nested exception java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.JoinColumn.foreignKey()?

If the issue is indeed with the foreignKey, then why does the problem not occur on Jetty?

spring.version    4.0.4.RELEASE

hibernate.version 4.3.5.Final

dataSource: class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.JoinColumn.foreignKey()Ljavax/persistence/ForeignKey`

This exception occurs of there are conflicting version of javax.persistence.ForeignKey class. Check your classpath and if you are using maven check the dependencies.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I am using maven. I shall check straight away.

Comment: If you are using eclipse and maven is integrated with eclipse, then you can get the complete dependency hierarchy of dependencies in pom.xml .

Comment: Thanks, I just checked, and that class lives in .m2/repository/org/hibernate/javax/persistence/hibernate-jpa-2.1-api/1.0.0.Final/hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final-sources.jar. That is contained in hibernate-core 4.3.5.Final. But I still don't know why that is causing a problem in Tomcat and not Jetty. Thanks once more.

Comment: Check the dependencies in pom.xml . There could be multiple versions of the jar having this class, may be through transitive dependency.

Comment: Thanks, Gaurav. I just checked. It turns out that org.jadira.usertype - usertype.core - 3.1.0.CR6 is using hibernate-jpa-2.0-api, an earlier version. I was using that dependency to get around the joda-time persistence issue with time stamp. Thank you very, very much.

Comment: How do you explain the issue only shows up on Tomcat and not on Jetty ? I'm asking because I have the same issue. I'm using usertype.jodatime 2.0.1 and hibernate 4.3.6.Final.

Answer (score 0):

For me, issue fixed after downgrading my project to java 6 and hibernate-entitymanager version to 3.6.9.FINAL